# Wsgi script and the newest django with Python 3.5

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

We are trying to deploy one more web-application on our VPS. 
There is one flask application in production already, which is held by Python 3.5 interpreter.

Now we need another one - django app. We have configured our apache2 to host both of then (django is working on subdomain, whereas flask is on the 'root' domain. Everything is okay here. 
But, since flask application is using global python interpreter (version 3.5) we cannot run django since it requires version 3.6 or newer.

Here is django WSGI script:

```
import os
import sys

print('Python version is ... ') # 3.5

python_home = '/var/www/mysite/venv'
activate_this = python_home + '/bin/activate_this.py'
exec(   open(activate_this).read()  )
print(sys.executable) # in case of virtualenv it refers to /usr/bin/python3.5
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/mysite/mysite")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

We could have upgraded our interpreter to 3.6, but since established flask app is in production we are not allowed to do so by our managers.. And it is okay probably

If we go with virtualenv nevertheless it created virtual environment with existing global interpreter , as is written above version 3.5.

And this is where we are stuck now. Apache2 log is constanlty saying to us:

```
[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=10081): Target WSGI script '/var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=10081): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error]  File "/var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
 [wsgi:error] from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error]  ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

If we run `python3` in terminal and then `from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application`
we are going to git this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/crypto.py", line 6, in <module>
import secrets
ImportError: No module named 'secrets'
```

And we assume that upgrading would solved our problem since django requires version 3.6 
https://github.com/quolc/neural-collage/issues/2 and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/ ("This tutorial is written for Django 3.0, which supports Python 3.6 and later ... ")

What will be the best step here? Trying to download and establish python 3.6 or newer and refer our wsgi to that or try to use another version of django ...?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Django 2.2 supports Python 3.5, is a long term support release, and will be supported until April 2022.

Comment: use virtualenvs and create a virtualenv for python3.6 by specifying the python version when you are creating the virtualenv.

Comment: If you install Python 3.6 on the same system, you'll hit the issue that mod_wsgi can only be compiled for one version of Python. You could get around this by installing [mod_wsgi-express](https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/) into one (or both) of your virtual environments.

Comment: Also, consider whether you could install the Django application on a different VPS. You could then modify the flask and Django installations without risking breaking the other (which seems to be a priority for your management). The downside is that it would cost more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case that was pretty easy. I was foolish to install and configured all my python services with sudo privileges , that is why when I did

```
pip3 install <package-name>
```

that all went okay, but since all services have been run under root I could not get package in usage, so I did

```
sudo pip3 install <package-name>
```

And have managed to localize the issue